# WSUS: Unapproved and Declined updates after local import

Tags: windows-server-2016, wsus-offline

OS: W2K16

I need to create a WSUS server from existed local repo. I did this steps:

- I  installed the feature and  dependencies.
- I Putted "Replica" option.
- And the repo folder contains db.gz file.

The command wsusutils.exe with import has been run but...

- Unapproved Updates: 244
- Declined updates: 21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found:

```
"Not Approved" is the default state that an update comes in with (inherited to all groups). When you select "Not Approved", you're replacing the inherited (lack of) approval with your explicit lack of approval - in effect, nothing is changed, and the update will still be shown as needed.

The "Decline" state is global, and cannot be assigned per group.
```

From: [https://serverfault.com/questions/357215/needed-counts-in-wsus-show-declined-updates][1]

To change the status to approved with:

```
1.- I unselect "No replica option Selected" on "WSUS administration console/Options". He ungrey "Accept" button.

2.- Always in Wsus Admin Console: Update Services/HOSTNAME/Updates/All Updates. I can accept the group of updates or update by update
```

Cordially!